# Bootstrapped charge pump design for phase frequency detector

Tags: pll, charge-pump

I'm trying design a charge pump as it's showed in the following link:

https://ibb.co/DDc6DsF (for some reason I couldn't upload it, I don't know why).
[image]
what I don't understand is what is \$I_{ref}\$ (the current on the left circuit) and how I can calculate it by the equation of Mosfet transistor equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the FETS around Iref are just mirrors, Iref becomes the ICP output.

The mirroring accuracy assumes the 0.18 micron channel lengths is adequate to tolerate Ids mismatches between diode-connected FETs and common-source-connected FETs.